# Как сделать проверку чекбокса?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как сделать проверку чекбокса в момент отправки формы? Должны проверяться сразу все `input` элементы, а у `checkbox` добавляется класс `is-invalid`, когда он выбран, запутался с этим.

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".form-container");

  form.addEventListener("submit", (evt) => {
    if (!validateForm()) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    } else {
      validateForm();
    }
  });

  const validationRules = {
    required: {
      test: (val) => { return val.length > 0 },
      error: (field) => `Please enter a valid ${field}`,
    },
    email: {
      test: (val) => {
        let regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9-]+.+.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

        return regex.test(val)
      },
      error: (field) => `Please enter a valid ${field}`
    },
  };

  const fileFields = Array.prototype.slice.call(form.querySelectorAll('[data-field]')).map(field => {
    let entry = field.querySelector('[data-validate]');

    return {
      wrap: field,
      entry: entry,
      message: field.querySelector('[data-validate-mess]'),
      rules: !!entry.dataset.validate ? entry.dataset.validate.split('|') : [],
      validateName: !!entry.dataset.validateAs ? entry.dataset.validateAs : entry.name,
      isValid: null
    };
  });


  fileFields.forEach((item) => {
    if(item.rules.length) {
      item.entry.addEventListener('change', () => {
        validateField(item);
      });
    }
  });

  const validateForm = () => {
    let formIsValid = true;
    fileFields.forEach(field => {
      formIsValid = validateField(field) ? formIsValid : false;
    });

    return formIsValid;
  }

  const validateField = (field) => {
    field.isValid = true;

    field.rules.forEach(rule => {
      if(validationRules.hasOwnProperty(rule) &&
        !validationRules[rule].test(field.entry.value)) {
        field.isValid = false;
        showError(field, validationRules[rule].error(field.validateName));
      } else if (validationRules.hasOwnProperty(rule) && field.entry.checked) {
        field.isValid = false;
        showError(field, validationRules[rule].error(field.validateName));
      }

    });

    if(field.isValid){
      hideError(field);
    }
    return field.isValid;

  }

  const showError = (field, message) => {
    field.message.innerHTML = message;
    field.wrap.classList.add('is-invalid');
  }

  const hideError = (field) => {
    field.message.innerHTML = '';
    field.wrap.classList.remove('is-invalid');
  }
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <form class="form" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-input" data-field="">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" data-validate="name|required" data-validate-as="name">
      <span class="error" data-validate-mess=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input" data-field="">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email" type="text" data-validate="email|required" data-validate-as="email">
      <span class="error" data-validate-mess=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input" data-field="">
      <input id="privacy" type="checkbox" data-validate="checked|required" data-validate-as="checkbox">
      <label for="privacy">I agree</label>
      <span class="error" data-validate-mess=""></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Send</button> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: "чекбокс выбивает ошибку" - ??

Comment: какая ошибка при нажатом чекбоксе?

Comment: Её не должно быть, просто по нажатию на кнопку отправки формы с пустыми полями должно всё подсветиться красным, а у меня 2 поля подсвечиваются а чекбокс сам по себе и я не понимаю чего так

Comment: вы пишите в `validateField`:  `else if (validationRules.hasOwnProperty(rule) && field.entry.checked) {
        field.isValid = false;`
как я понял, вам нужно подсвечивать чекбокс при `!(field.entry.checked)`

Comment: Да правильно, но теперь другие поля после заполнения остаются с ошибкой(

Comment: потому что эту проверку нужно проводить для `field` у которого тип будет `checkbox`, добавьте к условию `&& field.type == 'checkbox'`

Comment: Хм, у вас это работает? Куда бы я не добавлял то что вы написали, всё ровно поведение такое же

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129206/discussion-between--and-highpassion).

Comment: оформлю ответ сейчас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так должно сработать только на `field.validateName`, у которого значение `checkbox`

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".form-container");

  form.addEventListener("submit", (evt) => {
    if (!validateForm()) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    } else {
      validateForm();
    }
  });

  const validationRules = {
    required: {
      test: (val) => { return val.length > 0 },
      error: (field) => `Please enter a valid ${field}`,
    },
    email: {
      test: (val) => {
        let regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9-]+.+.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

        return regex.test(val)
      },
      error: (field) => `Please enter a valid ${field}`
    },
  };

  const fileFields = Array.prototype.slice.call(form.querySelectorAll('[data-field]')).map(field => {
    let entry = field.querySelector('[data-validate]');

    return {
      wrap: field,
      entry: entry,
      message: field.querySelector('[data-validate-mess]'),
      rules: !!entry.dataset.validate ? entry.dataset.validate.split('|') : [],
      validateName: !!entry.dataset.validateAs ? entry.dataset.validateAs : entry.name,
      isValid: null
    };
  });


  fileFields.forEach((item) => {
    if(item.rules.length) {
      item.entry.addEventListener('change', () => {
        validateField(item);
      });
    }
  });

  const validateForm = () => {
    let formIsValid = true;
    fileFields.forEach(field => {
      formIsValid = validateField(field) ? formIsValid : false;
    });

    return formIsValid;
  }

  const validateField = (field) => {
    field.isValid = true;

    field.rules.forEach(rule => {
      if(validationRules.hasOwnProperty(rule) &&
        !validationRules[rule].test(field.entry.value)) {
        field.isValid = false;
        showError(field, validationRules[rule].error(field.validateName));
      } else if (validationRules.hasOwnProperty(rule) && !(field.entry.checked) && field.validateName == "checkbox" ) {
        field.isValid = false;
        showError(field, validationRules[rule].error(field.validateName));
      }

    });

    if(field.isValid){
      hideError(field);
    }
    return field.isValid;

  }

  const showError = (field, message) => {
    field.message.innerHTML = message;
    field.wrap.classList.add('is-invalid');
  }

  const hideError = (field) => {
    field.message.innerHTML = '';
    field.wrap.classList.remove('is-invalid');
  }
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <form class="form" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-input" data-field="">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" data-validate="name|required" data-validate-as="name">
      <span class="error" data-validate-mess=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input" data-field="">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email" type="text" data-validate="email|required" data-validate-as="email">
      <span class="error" data-validate-mess=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input" data-field="">
      <input id="privacy" type="checkbox" data-validate="checked|required" data-validate-as="checkbox">
      <label for="privacy">I agree</label>
      <span class="error" data-validate-mess=""></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Send</button> 
  </form>
</div>
```